# Statistitical differences pairwise comparisions on binomial data

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I am running a inhibition of growth assay on bacteria on R. I've got a dataframe with the different bacteria and different concentrations, and my response variable, inhibition, being 1 if there is inhibition, and 0 if there is not inhibition.

| Bacteria | Concentration | Inhibition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lactobacillus | 95 | 1 |
| Lactobacillus | 95 | 1 |
| Lactobacillus | 95 | 0 |
| Lactobacillus | 9.5 | 0 |
| Lactobacillus | 9.5 | 0 |
| Lactobacillus | 9.5 | 0 |
| Bifodobacterium | 95 | 1 |
| Bifidobacterium | 95 | 1 |
| Bifidobacterium | 95 | 1 |

Like this, I run this code to see if the concentration had an effect on inhibition.

```r
inhibition <- glmer(Inhibition ~ Concentration + (1|Bacteria), 
                    data = Growth_data, family = binomial)

inhib2 <- glmer(Inhibition ~ (1|Bacteria), data = Growth_data, 
                family = binomial)

anova(inhibition, inhib2)
```

I get that the concentration has an effect on inhibition, but now I want to see the pairwise comparisons of the effect of concentration on each of the bacteria. I subsetted each of the bacteria, and now I cannot use glmer function anymore, as the random factor (Bacteria) is the same for all. I adapted then a glm function like this, and did subsequent pairwise comparisions:

```r
ps_Lacto <- subset(Growth_data, Growth_data$Bacteria == 
                   "Lactobacillus")

inhibLacto <- glm(formula = Inhibition ~ factor(Concentration), 
                  family = binomial(logit),
                  data = ps_Lacto)

lsmeans(inhibLacto, pairwise ~ Concentration)
```

This pairwise comparison seems to not be working that well, since it says that all the concentrations are the same and there are no differences.

Do you know any other way that this could be done that is more reliable?

Comment: what does this show:  `with(ps_Lacto, tapply(Inhibition, factor(Concentration), FUN=mean) )`

Comment: It's unclearly from your question why you think bacteria should have a random effect. If you are interested the effect of concentration on each species, then it would appear you think it has a fixed effect.

Comment: There is no law that says any pairwise differences have to be significant, even if the anova F is. Second, when differences are nonsignificant, it is careless and wrong to say the means are the same. Third, your first model should have factor(Concentration) in it; and with that change you can (and should) use lsmeans with that model, instead of subsetting the data.

Comment: @DWin I get this result:0.95  9.50 95.00 
                                     0.6   0.6   0.8                                                                                   (There are more bacteria and concentrations in my dataframe but I only copied a part of it)

Comment: #@IanCampbell The bacteria were grown seperatedly in three diferent concentrations, and one being inhibited does not mean the rest ave to be so that I why I thought I should add the bacteria as a random effect, do you think I should add it as a fixed effect? In such case, I cannot use the glmer function, as I do not have a random effect

Comment: Hi @RussLenth, I am sorry, what I meant is that the lsmeans comparisions showed no statistical differences between concentrarions of the same bacteria,and that's why I thought about it as odd when tehre is an effect of concentration. I created a model where I added the factor(Concentration) to the glmer function,as you suggested, and then when applying the lsmeans in that model I get the concentrasts between the three concentrations across all bacteria, but not for each, which is what I am looking for, and that's is why I subseted the data. Do you know a way to do it?

Comment: So in other words, Bacteria is not a random effect - as implied by your model?

Comment: @RussLenth, yes it seems I got it wrong. In such case, I should use a glm function like this? `Inhibitionassay <-glm(formula = Inhibition ~ Bacteria+factor(Concentration), family = binomial(logit),
                      data = Growth_data)`? The pairwise comparisions could be done with the lsmeans(Inhibitionassay, pairwise=Concentration*Bacteria), but I get every single interaction, is there any easy way to perform this? Sorry, I don't have a lot of experience with R.